# Throw an error when trying to delete non-allowed property

Tags: javascript

So I know you can prevent a property from being deleted by setting the `configurable` property on the object to `false`. However the only feedback you get from this delete action is a boolean that shows true or false. Is there any way to throw an error immediately when a non-allowed property is being deleted?

```js
const obj = {
  deleteMe: "Some text",
  dontDeleteMe: "Some other text"
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'dontDeleteMe', {
    value: "Some text",
    writable : true,
    enumerable : true,
    configurable : false
});


console.log(Object.keys(obj));
delete obj.deleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
delete obj.dontDeleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

Comment: Adding a Proxy to your object might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/deleteProperty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An error would throw if you add `use strict`:

```js
'use strict';
const obj = {
  deleteMe: "Some text",
  dontDeleteMe: "Some other text"
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'dontDeleteMe', {
    value: "Some text",
    writable : true,
    enumerable : true,
    configurable : false
});


console.log(Object.keys(obj));
delete obj.deleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
delete obj.dontDeleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

With [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
const obj = {
  deleteMe: "Some text",
  dontDeleteMe: "Some other text"
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'dontDeleteMe', {
    value: "Some text",
    writable : true,
    enumerable : true,
    configurable : false
});

const handler1 = {
  deleteProperty(target, prop) {
    delete target[prop];
    if (target[prop]) {
      throw new Error(`Invalid attempt to delete '${prop}' property`);
    }
    return true;
  }
};

const proxyObj = new Proxy(obj, handler1);
console.log(Object.keys(proxyObj));
delete proxyObj.deleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(proxyObj));
delete proxyObj.dontDeleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(proxyObj));
```

Comment: When looking at using the proxy, couldn't I just use  `prop !== 'dontDeleteMe` inside the deletehandler to disallow deletion instead of also setting configurable to false? Or does this approach have an advantage?

Comment: They are both correct, you can use `prop !== 'dontDeleteMe` or set configurable and make a dyamic test in the handler like I have done, the advantage of setting configurable is to avoid deleting the property accedentally by doing `delete obj.dontDeleteMe` intead of `delete proxyObj.dontDeleteMe`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `"use strict";` with `Object.defineProperty()` or `Object.freeze()`

Visit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_delete) for details

```
'use strict';
var obj = Object.freeze({name: 'Elsa', score: 157});
delete obj.score;  // TypeError

'use strict';
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {value: 2, configurable: false});
delete obj.foo;  // TypeError

'use strict';
var frozenArray = Object.freeze([0, 1, 2]);
frozenArray.pop();  // TypeError
```

With your code:

```js
"use strict";
const obj = {
  deleteMe: "Some text",
  dontDeleteMe: "Some other text"
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'dontDeleteMe', {
    value: "Some text",
    writable : true,
    enumerable : true,
    configurable : false
});


console.log(Object.keys(obj));
delete obj.deleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
delete obj.dontDeleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

Comment: I would rather not freeze the object, it should still be editable. I just want prevent deletion of certain properties and throw an error it is attempted. Your 'use strict' suggestion is a good, however if possible I would like a solution not requiring strict mode necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use "use strict" (for whatever reasons) this would be the proxy solution:

```js
const obj = {
  deleteMe: "Some text",
  dontDeleteMe: "Some other text"
};

const deleteHandler = {
  deleteProperty(target, prop) {
    if (prop in target) {
      const deleted = delete target[prop];
      if (!deleted) {
        console.error(`deletion not allowed: ${prop}`);
      }
    }
  }
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'dontDeleteMe', {
  value: "Some text",
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false
});

const proxyObj = new Proxy(obj, deleteHandler);

console.log(Object.keys(proxyObj));
delete proxyObj.deleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(proxyObj));
delete proxyObj.dontDeleteMe;
console.log(Object.keys(proxyObj));
```

Comment: Should I still set configurable explicitly to false if I can just check the property name in the deleteHandler?

Comment: This depends on your use case. It's safer to keep it. But of course you could configure erasability only inside your deleteHandler.